# How to retrieve the outermost relation through multiple nested relations in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

While exploring Laravel's model relationships, I've stumbled upon a question I myself haven't found an answer for.

Consider a user which can have multiple contact lists, and each contact list may have multiple phone numbers. Each phone number can be a part of multiple contact lists, and these contact lists can belong to multiple users.

The task is to retrieve the list of all users having the provided phone number in at least one of their contact lists.

Here is the structure of these models in Laravel:

The **User** model:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphMany;

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get contact lists of the user.
     */
    public function lists(): MorphMany
    {
        return $this->morphMany(ContactList::class, 'container');
    }
}
```

The **ContactList** model:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphTo;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany;

class ContactList extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the container of this contact list (a user or something else).
     */
    public function container(): MorphTo
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    /**
     * Get phone numbers in that list.
     */
    public function numbers(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(PhoneNumber::class);
    }
}
```

The **PhoneNumber** model:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany;

class PhoneNumber extends Model
{
    /**
     * Retrieve the contact lists for the number.
     */
    public function lists(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(ContactList::class);
    }
}
```

The question here is how do I implement the method `users()` in a `PhoneNumber` model so that I get all necessary relations associated with it?

Comment: Can you add sample rows from each of the relevant tables showing the relationships? Always find these polymorphic relationships to be confusing to deal with.

Comment: Why don't you use a User ~~> belongsToMany ~~> ContactList?

Comment: @Pippo I am looking for a way to get users from a phone number interface by using relationships. Your suggestion involves getting all contact lists of a certain user, which is not what I am looking for.

Comment: @miken32 They are irrelevant in context of question, as the question is only about the relationships between tables, regardless of their content.

Comment: @Rusurano I meant that, from the information provided, it appears that a more complicated approach has been taken, than is needed

Comment: It’s easier to grok the relationship with sample data to go on is all. Good luck I guess

Answer (score -1):

you could try this library: https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep

with it you will be able to establish a direct relationship in your model.

I find it a bit difficult to give you the relationship with the keys in the correct order, but I am confident that when you look at the methods offered in this package you will find the solution.